# Excel VBA - How can dates of different formats be compared

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare the dates from two different worksheets which have different formats. The first sheet's format is YYYYMMDD, and the second's is DD/MM/YYYY.

A caveat is the second worksheet's year is incorrect (it written as 2020 and should be 2021). The rows may also be in different orders. The first worksheet's data for the date is input as Text and not Date.

As much as I would like to, I can't change the data on these two sheets, and can instead only output to a third sheet (essentially checking the data for entries with the same date, not counting the incorrect year, and outputting something if some key data is different between them).

For example, if one sheet has...

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 20210101 | 500 |
| 20210102 | 1000 |
| 20210103 | 2000 |

...and the other has...

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 500 |
| 03/01/2020 | 3000 |
| 02/01/2020 | 750 |

...I would want to output this to the third sheet...

| Date | Sheet 1 Price | Sheet 2 Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20210102 | 1000 | 750 |
| 20210103 | 2000 | 3000 |

I have some VBA code which would work in principal, but only if the formats were identical.

```
' the columns to check in the first worksheet
Const ws1Date As Integer = 1          'first worksheet, Column A
Const ws1Price As Integer = 2         'first worksheet, Column B

' the columns to check in the second worksheet
Const ws2Date As Integer = 1         'second worksheet, Column A
Const ws2Price As Integer = 2        'second worksheet, Column B

' the columns to write to in the result worksheet
Const resultWsDate As Integer = 1          'result worksheet, Column A
Const resultWsPrice As Integer = 2         'result worksheet, Column B
Const resultWsClientPrice As Integer = 3   'result worksheet, Column C

Dim ws1DateArray As Variant, ws2DateArray As Variant
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, resultWs As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets(1) 'the first worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(2) 'the second worksheet
Set resultWs = Sheets(3) 'the outputted results

Sub compareFiles()

'-- Store ws1 dates in array --
compareRowMaxLength = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, ws1Date).End(xlUp).Row
ws1DateArray = ws1.Range(Cells(1, ws1Date).Address, _
                       Cells(compareRowMaxLength, ws1Date).Address).Value
                       
'-- Store ws2 dates in array --
compareRowMaxLength = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, ws2Date).End(xlUp).Row
ws2DateArray = ws2.Range(Cells(1, ws2Date).Address, _
                       Cells(compareRowMaxLength, ws2Date).Address).Value

'-- Store ws1 depth in array --
compareRowMaxLength = resultWs.Cells(Rows.Count, ws1Date).End(xlUp).Row
ws1DepthArray = resultWs.Range(Cells(1, ws1Date).Address, _
                       Cells(compareRowMaxLength, ws1Depth).Address).Value

'-- Interate through arrays --
For compareRow = 2 To UBound(ws2DateArray, 1)
    matchData = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    
    matchData = WorksheetFunction.Match(ws2DateArray(compareRow, 1), ws1DateArray, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' if the date of the current row is found in the second sheet
    If matchData <> 0 Then
        If ws2.Cells(compareRow, ws2Price).Value <> ws1.Cells(matchData, ws1Price).Value Then
            ' Copy the matching data to the results worksheet
            resultWs.Cells(resultRow, resultWsDate).Value = ws1.Cells(matchData, ws1Date).Value
            resultWs.Cells(resultRow, resultWsPrice).Value = ws1.Cells(matchData, ws1Price).Value
            resultWs.Cells(resultRow, resultWsClientPrice).Value = ws2.Cells(compareRow, ws2Price).Value
        End If
    End If
Next compareRow

End Sub
```

I have tried to reformat the date from sheet 2 using something like this within the For loop...

```
    ReplacementYear = 2021
    
    FormatDay = Left(ws2DateArray(compareRow, 1), 2)
    FormatMonth = Mid(ws2DateArray(compareRow, 1), 4, 2)
    FormattedDate = CStr(ReplacementYear) + CStr(FormatMonth) + CStr(FormatDay)
```

...and changing `matchData = WorksheetFunction.Match(ws2DateArray(compareRow, 1), ws1DateArray, 0)` to `matchData = WorksheetFunction.Match(FormatDate, ws1DateArray, 0)` but it seems Match can't work this way.

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: How are these dates stored?  Excel stores "real dates" as serial numbers starting with `1-Jan-1900`.  If both are "real dates" and it is only the format that is different, compare the .Value2 property (it should be a Double or Long, **NOT an INTEGER**). If the difference is the data type, and not the format, suggest you convert to a real date, then do your comparison.

Comment: When you click on the cell which has `20210102`,, check the formula bar. What do you see?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The first worksheet stores the dates as text, not a "real date". The second sheet, however, does have it sored as a date. Thanks, I'll try and see if I can do that. I can't modify the first worksheet at all (in reality both are separate workbooks that I can only look at and not edit, pulled into a report on a third workbook), so I'll have to convert it through the macro.

@SiddharthRout The first sheet is `20210102` (entered as Text), and the second is `02/01/2020` (entered as Date).

Comment: You will have to convert that into a real date to do a direct comparision. Use `DateSerial(Left(Range("A1").Value2, 4), Mid(Range("A1").Value2, 5, 2), Right(Range("A1").Value2, 2))` to convert `20210102` into a date to do the comparision

Comment: If you are interested, all of the above can also be done in Power Query. It does require using Tables for your sheet1 and sheet2 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may well not be the best solution, but in the off-chance this helps anyone in the future, this is what I came up with.

I can't modify the data in the other worksheets, but I can copy the data into a new worksheet, modify that, and then remove it later on.

```
' copy the worksheets and modify dates
ws1.Copy After:=Sheets(4)
ws2.Copy After:=Sheets(5)

Set modifyWs1 = Sheets(4)
Set modifyWs2 = Sheets(5)

' fix dates and apply consistent formatting to dates and depth
modifyWs1 .Activate

Dim ws1DateCol As Range

For Each ws1DateCol In Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    ws1DateCol.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd" ' confirm date format
    ws1DateCol.Value = ws1DateCol.Text ' change cells to text so they can be Matched
    ws1DateCol.NumberFormat = "@"
Next

' fix dates and apply consistent formatting to dates and depth
modifyWs2.Activate

Dim ws2DateCol As Range

For Each ws2DateCol In Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    ws2DateCol.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, ws2DateCol.Value) ' add 1 to the year, as 2020 should be 2021
    ws2DateCol.NumberFormat = "yyyymmdd" ' change date format
    ws2DateCol.Value = ws2DateCol.Text ' change cells to text so they can be Matched
    ws2DateCol.NumberFormat = "@"
Next
```

The data from these new columns are then put into the `ws1DateArray` and `ws2DateArray` instead, and the `WorksheetFunction.Match(ws2DateArray(compareRow, 1), ws1DateArray, 0)` works as desired.